# customizing the space inside the stepper widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Are there any way on how do I customize(removing/adjusting) the space inside the `Stepper Widget` in Flutter?

here is the snippet of my Stepper, tried wrapping it in a `Container` widget and tried using `EdgeInsets.zero` in both `margin and padding`. However it did not work. Here is the snippet of my code..

```
child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            canvasColor: Colors.yellow,
            colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
                  primary: Colors.green,
                  background: Colors.red,
                  secondary: Colors.green,
                ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Stepper(///...codes here...///)
```

[and here is the image of the space that I wanna adjust or remove in Stepper..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfbTV.png)